# ASP.NET MVC Multiple Routes and invalid route dictionary value

Tags: dictionary, routes

I have multiple route to display detail information about store and product information. it is defined on Global.asax as the following

```
routes.MapRoute("DetailProduct",
    "{controller}/{action}/{ProductGUID}/{CategoryGUID}/{StoreGUID}/{UserID}",
            new {
                controller = "Home", action = "DetailProducts",
                  ProductGUID = UrlParameter.Optional,
                  CategoryGUID = UrlParameter.Optional,
                  UserID = UrlParameter.Optional,

            });

routes.MapRoute("StoreInfo",  "{controller}/{action}/{StoreGUID}/{StoreCountryLocation}/{StoreName}/{StoreUserID}",
       new
       {
           controller = "Home",
           action = "DetailStore",
           StoreGUID = UrlParameter.Optional,
           StoreCountryLocation = UrlParameter.Optional,
           StoreName = UrlParameter.Optional,
           StoreUserID = UrlParameter.Optional
       }
       );
```

the following hyperlink are defined on ASPX file to execute those map route StoreInfo and DetailProduct.

**Storeinfo**

```
 <a href=<%: Url.RouteUrl("StoreInfo", new RouteValueDictionary(new { Controller = "Home", Action = "DetailStore", StoreGUID = itemList.StoreGUID, StoreCountryLocation = itemList.Country, StoreName = itemList.StoreName, StoreUserID = itemList.UserID }))%>>                                                                 
</a>
```

**Detail Product**

```
<a href=<%= Url.RouteUrl("DetailProduct", new RouteValueDictionary( new { controller="Home",action="DetailProducts",ProductGUID=itemList.productGUID,CategoryGUID=itemList.CategoryGUID,UserID=itemList.UserID,StoreGUID=itemList.StoreGUID})) %>> </a>
```

Nevertheless, when **storeinfo** hyperlink is clicked, Detail product route dictionary values are given instead of storeinfo route value dictionary

```
?RouteData.Values.Keys  
Count = 6
    [0]: "controller"
    [1]: "action"
    [2]: "ProductGUID"
    [3]: "CategoryGUID"
    [4]: "StoreGUID"
    [5]: "UserID"
```

Could you please advise?

Comment: remove the asterixes, they are not applying bold. The detailProduct route doesn't have storeguid in its dictionary.

Comment: Dallas, sorry to forgot to put storeguid in its dictionary. the problem is still occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you are getting conflicts in your parameters.  Because you have marked everything as optional, and even have the controller and action being 'dynamic'.

It looks like you are targetting fixed actions, so you could do your maproutes like so:

```
routes.MapRoute("DetailProduct",
"Home/DetailsProducts/{ProductGUID}/{CategoryGUID}/{StoreGUID}/{UserID}",
        new {
              ProductGUID = UrlParameter.Optional,
              CategoryGUID = UrlParameter.Optional,
              UserID = UrlParameter.Optional,

        });

routes.MapRoute("StoreInfo",  "Home/DetailStore/{StoreGUID}/{StoreCountryLocation}/{StoreName}/{StoreUserID}",
   new
   {
       StoreGUID = UrlParameter.Optional,
       StoreCountryLocation = UrlParameter.Optional,
       StoreName = UrlParameter.Optional,
       StoreUserID = UrlParameter.Optional
   }
   );
```